# Who adds BeginInvoke, Invoke and EndInvoke method definitions to a typed delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates

e.g. if you write...
`public delegate void MyTypedDel(int x)`
Intellisense shows that BeginInvoke, Invoke and EndInvoke are part of the MyTypedDel type definition.
They are not part of the Delegate or MulticastDelegate type definition. (Delegate has a DynamicInvoke method, which uses late/runtime binding to bind to a method.)

So my question is where are these methods mixed in to the typed delegate type definition and how does its implementation look like? I read that... Invoke internally calls BeginInvoke and EndInvoke in succession on the same thread. Is this true?

Just curious as to the magic under the hood here.. Maybe I missed something real obvious... in which case be brutal :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler generates your delegate class, which extends the `Delegate` BCL class and adds methods specific to the signature of your delegate. You can see this by looking at your delegate (or a BCL delegate) in reflector and switching to IL view (since the C# disassembler is smart enough to turn it back into a delegate declaration). Example:

```
.class public auto ansi sealed WaitCallback
    extends System.MulticastDelegate
{
    .custom instance void System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute::.ctor(bool) = { bool(true) }
    .method public hidebysig specialname rtspecialname instance void .ctor(object 'object', native int 'method') runtime managed
    {
    }

    .method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance class System.IAsyncResult BeginInvoke(object state, class System.AsyncCallback callback, object 'object') runtime managed
    {
    }

    .method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance void EndInvoke(class System.IAsyncResult result) runtime managed
    {
    }

    .method public hidebysig newslot virtual instance void Invoke(object state) runtime managed
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are the .method blocks empty.. as in where is the implementation/IL for these methods? Where are these calls routed to ?

Comment: I think it's related to the runtime managed metadata. I'm guessing that's equivalent to an InternalCall, meaning the CLR implements those methods internally.

Comment: Found my answer in CLR via C# 2.0 by Jeffrey Richter - Chapter on Delegates. When you use the delegate keyword, the compiler creates a new Type derived from MulticastDelegate and adds a ctor, Invoke() with the same signature as the delegate you specifed and the corresponding BeginInvoke() and EndInvoke().

Answer (score 1):

The compiler does most of this work (see Kent's reply). Re the question about calling Begin/End in succession; no, not for delegates. You can verify this, because `BeginInvoke` pushes the work onto the `ThreadPool`, where-as if you use `Invoke` the work happens on the current thread.

This approach, however, is common some other Begin/End pairs (in particular IO-bound operations); but not for delegates.

I've been looking at more graceful ways of calling Begin/End (without messing with `IAsyncResult` etc) - [see here for more](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/02/async-without-pain.html).